# Setting LIMIT() on Cassandra table in JavaRDD does not work

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver, spark-cassandra-connector

Cassandra 2.2.8. java8
I am using limit 100 but I get 600 rows

```
JavaRDD<TransByDate> originDateRDD = javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable(" ")
                .select(" ")).limit((long)100);

long cnt1= originDateRDD.count();
System.out.println("originDateRDD.count: "+cnt1);
```

=> Prints 600

Whatever limit I set I get **6 times** the rows

Comment: And looking at the rows does not give a hint why you might consistently get 6 times the limit number of rows?

Comment: @Ralf - not really. I don't know why I should get rows more than the Limit. The table has compound keys (2) + a sort key.

Comment: I did some basic row analysis - could not see any pattern. I am actually selecting only the 2 Key columns (and not the sort key) - some rows repeat 2 some 3 some 5 times. So no pattern as such.

Comment: And no row repeats 6 times